# Symfony 2 entity as hidden?

Tags: php, symfony

Suppose i have an entity
 `ServiceOffer{id ...}`
 and
 `ServiceOfferCapabilities{serviceoffer_id , capability_id,value }` .

ServiceOffer has a collection of ServiceOfferCapabilities  (one to many) . All i want is display a form of ServiceOffer and let the user choose the value he wants for each capability.

Well  no matter what i do this is very difficult. Because i dont know how to create formType for ServiceOfferCapabilities. I add value as text for example but i dont know how to add capability.
I can make it work but on submit there are problems , because it doesnt know which is the capability and  it sets it to null. I tried hidden but it fails to create a capability object with desired id.. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to look that you need something like [data translator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) that (from link)

> Say you have a one-to-one relation of Task to Issue, e.g. a Task
>   optionally has an issue linked to it. Adding a listbox with all
>   possible issues can eventually lead to a really long listbox in which
>   it is impossible to find something. You might want to add a textbox
>   instead, where the user can simply enter the issue number.
>
> You could try to do this in your controller, but it's not the best
>   solution. It would be better if this issue were automatically
>   converted to an Issue object. This is where Data Transformers come
>   into play.

Comment: that was the solution , data transformer  with get reference.